# Setting a state in react.js with two-way binding

Tags: reactjs

i'am working in a project using react.js and fire-base, i have a form when i set the input with my state that is fill with data of fire-base, and is working i can update and create new registry, but i think that my `onChangeHandle()` for the inputs is not the correct way to do it.

```
This is my form:
render(){
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
            <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Nombre de Proyecto</label>
                        <input type='text' value={this.state.proyectName} onChange={(event)=>this.onChangeHandle('p',event)}className="form-control" id="project_name"/>

                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Inspiracion</label>
                        <textarea  value={this.state.inspiration} onChange={(event)=>this.onChangeHandle('i',event)} rows="4" cols="50" className="form-control" id="inspiration"/>

                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Que problema resuelve</label>
                        <textarea  value={this.state.whatDoes} onChange={(event)=>this.onChangeHandle('w',event)} rows="4" cols="50" className="form-control" id="what_does"/>

                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label >Como esta hecho</label>
                        <textarea value={this.state.howBuild} onChange={(event)=>this.onChangeHandle('h',event)} rows="4" cols="50" className="form-control" id="how_build"/>

                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Integrantes</label>
                        <input type='text' className="form-control" id="team"/>

                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">

                        <button className="form-control btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>this.writeStartupData()} >Agregar </button>

                    </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

And here is my event handler:

```
onChangeHandle(exp,event){
        switch(exp){
            case "p":
                this.setState({
                proyectName: event.target.value,       
                });
                break;   
            case "i":
                this.setState({
                inspiration: event.target.value,       
                });
                break; 
            case "w":
                this.setState({
                whatDoes: event.target.value,       
                });
                break;
            case "h":
                this.setState({
                howBuild: event.target.value,       
                });
                break;
            case "t":
                this.setState({
                team: event.target.value,       
                });
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do something like this.

```
  <div className="form-group">
    <label >something</label>
    <input
        type='text'
        value={this.state.something}
        onChange={event => this.setState({something: event.target.value})}
        className="form-control" id="project_name"/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for your event handlers is not something I'd consider very readable, [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), or adherent to any react best practises.

Using an anonymous arrow function and calling setState from there, like @vitaliy-andrianov has done, is perfectly fine. There is just one downside with arrow functions in that case: the functions are re-created on every re-render, incurring a small (most likely negligible) performance penalty. It could also be a little more dry. Below is another acceptable alternative:

```
// Component class method
handleFormChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    [event.currentTarget.name]: event.currentTarget.value
  });
}

// ... and if you like destructuring
handleFormChange({currentTarget: {name, value}}) {
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
}


// An example input
<input
  className="form-control"
  name="proyectName"
  type="text"
  value={this.state.proyectName}
  onChange={this.handleFormChange} />
```

**Note:** I am passing `handleFormChange` directly to the `onChange` prop; for this to work, the function has to be bound to the scope of the class. So make sure you do that in the constructor (`this.handleFormChange.bind(this)`), or just use an arrow function.